# What is the closest word in English for "понт"?

Tags: перевод, английский

I tried to find closest word in English which means same as russian "понт" (not a geographical term, but a noun to "show off"), but failed. Is there any?

Comment: This is offtopic on this site. This site is for questions about Russian, not about English. Try to ask on http://english.stackexchange.com

Comment: I think this has something to do with precise translation, and it could be provided by some of russian-speakers who use English in practice. I doubt if I'm able to find these on english.stachexchange.com, but anyway posted a question there: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145238/what-is-the-closest-word-in-english-for-russian

Comment: Have you tried to look [here](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?CL=1&s=%EF%EE%ED%F2&l1=1) and [here](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?a=3&&s=%EF%EE%ED%F2&l1=2&l2=1)?

Comment: I think it's something that would have no exact translation as a single word. I would either restructure the sentence to describe the person who shows off (позёр) as a 'show-off', or just say "act of showing off".

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe "swag"?

Comment: It's brilliant! This question is marked as off-topic both at http://russian.stackexchange.com and http://english.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Constructor This is because it is asked on English L&U so that it is not understandible for English native speaker. This is why cross-post doesn't work. See also my comment below your answer.

Answer (score -1):

It is a copy of [my answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/145252/61716) at http://english.stackexchange.com:

> Some variants: bluff, flossing, airs, grandstanding, peacockery, lugs. Bells and whistles, dress-off (for russian word "понты" which has a slightly different meaning).

Comment: I don't think this was necessary to cross-post, since there are a lot of answers at English SE.

Comment: @Artemix I cross-posted my answer because this question was put on hold at [english.se] and I was afraid of its deletion. Sorry if it does not comply with the rules.

Comment: Ironically, on both forums asking for right translation is considered as "off topic". I have no other comments.

Comment: @AskarKalykov This is because on English L&U you have to describe what is the meaning of the word "понт" that it has in Russian (including all the expected connotations). You just posted the word itself. Your question there is like: "There is russian word **X** that is translated in English like **Y**. I don't like such translation." - since English speakers don't know Russian, they can just suggest synonyms of word **Y** which you already treated as wrong translation. So they can't help you in this case. If you want help from English native speakers you have to describe them what you want.

Comment: @Artemix I think it is too strange that this question is marked as off-topic at _both_ sites. It appears that questions about translation from some language to English are inappropriate even if some_language.se site exists, doesn't it?

Comment: @Constructor On different sites there are different rules. On Russian.SE there are many russian speakers, you can mix Russian with English and be understood. Most users of  English.SE community don't speak Russian, so the questions there should be written in English only.